# Convert an Excel column into a list of vectors in R

Tags: r, import-from-excel

I need to convert an Excel column into a list of vectors in R. The column only has stocks symbols names like APPL, GOOG, MSFT, etc. But many of them.

I accomplished to create a dataframe with the names of the stock but no success in creating a list the way I need.

> That's what I got:

```
 list_of_stocks <- read.table(file = "clipboard")
 head(list_of_stocks)
      V1
  1 APPL
  2 GOOG
  3 MSFT
  4 TTNP
  5 AVCO
  6 CCCL
```

As you can see it is structured as a data.frame.

```
str(list_of_stocks)
'data.frame':   123 obs. of  1 variable:
$ V1: Factor w/ 74 levels "APPL","ACHV",..: 32 57 2 68 10 18 71 8 71 69 ...
```

> That's what I need:

```
list_of_stocks 
    [1] "APPL" "GOOG" "MSFT" "TTNP" "AVCO" "CCCL"
```

I will be using this in the getSymbols function, so I can download multiple stocks in one time in a enviroment. 
I want to be able to use it like this:

```
getSymbols(list_of_stocks, env = stocks_research, auto.assign = TRUE)
```

Any help?

Comment: Just use `stingsAsFactors =FALSE)` in the `read.table`

Comment: thanks akrun! I used the stringsAsFactors and then I created a list with list_of_stocks[,1] since it only has one column. I applied to the getSymbols and it worked perfectly! awesome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What we find is the default behavior of `read.table/read.csv` or `data.frame` where the column types get automatically converted to `factor` if there is any string element as `stringsAsFactors = TRUE`.  Inorder to reset it, use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` and then extract the column

```
list_of_stocks <- read.table(file = "clipboard", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
list_of_stocks$V1
```